# PyTorch tokenizers: how to truncate tokens from left?

Tags: pytorch, tokenize, truncate, bert-language-model

As we can see in the below code snippet, specifying max_length and truncation for a tokenizer cuts excess tokens *from the left*:

```html
tokenizer("hello, my name", truncation=True, max_length=6).input_ids

> [0, 42891, 6, 127, 766, 2]

tokenizer("hello, my name", truncation=True, max_length=4).input_ids

> [0, 42891, 6, 2]
```

The different tokenization strategies like *only_second*, *only_first*, *longest_first*, all seem to cut from the right.  Is there a way to cut from the left? So that the tokens would be `[0, 127, 766, 2]` in the second example?

Comment: Not sure this is possible unfortunately, unless you implement a custom solution. I was looking for the same functionality but found these two GitHub issues which may be interesting to you: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/10519 and  https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/4476

Comment: There seems to be a solution in this PR https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/14947  
Bear in mind you need to set this feature when instantiating the tokeniser, NOT when calling it, for example like this

```tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', truncation_side='left')```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [andrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13066590/andrea) in the comments, you can use `truncation_side='left'` when initialising the tokenizer. You can also set this attribute after tokenizer creation:

```
tokenizer.truncation_side='left'. # Default is 'right'
```

The tokenizer internally takes care of the rest and truncates based on the `max_len` argument. Alternatively; if you need to use a `transformers` version which does not have this feature, you can tokenize without truncation and implement the following custom logic as a postprocessing step:

```
tokens = tokens[-max_len:]
attn_mask = attn_mask[-max_len:]
```